# Modelling "gaps" in a Poisson regression

Tags: poisson-distribution, generalized-estimating-equations

I am conducting an analysis into offending in relation to a time-dependent exposure - onset of heroin use, over a persons life. I am using poisson GEE with offending aggregate to a persons age-year. Many people have experienced time in prison, which means they can't experience the outcome, but are still experiencing the exposure. Including the reduced time (year minus proportion of year spent in prison) as an offset does not seem to be appropriate, as the exposure still applies. Is there any other modelling approaches you can recommend?